# Bourbon Neat Custom Container Size

Tags: bourbon, neat

I tried experimenting on Bourbon Neat trying to create basic layout such as:

- HEADER
- ARTICLE
- SIDEBAR
- FOOTER

What I want to achieve is, I wanted to create a container having a size of 970px though I could not get a fixed 970px instead I get 940px with a 15px gutter on each side.

how can I achieve 970px without gutters?

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try `grid-collapse`: https://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#grid-collapse

Comment: Thank you for the response mate. I will surely try this one out. Have a great day.